# Как сделать так,чтобы ответ "Да" или "Нет" выводился только 1 раз? (Python)

Tags: python, if, for

```
k = int(input("Введите число K:"))
for i in range(10, 99+1):
    if sum(map(int, list(str(i)))) == k:
        print("Да")
    else:
        print("Нет")
```

Comment: а что ваш код вообще должен делать то? если вы считаете сумму цифр числа, то почему только один раз должно ДА/НЕТ выводиться, если вы анализируете 90 чисел? что тогда должно означать это Да?

Comment: Вопрос не в коде,код для примера.Хочу узнать,как сделать так,чтобы из цикла for результат выводился 1 раз только.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
k = int(input("Введите число K: "))
rez = []

for i in range(10, 100):
    if sum(map(int, list(str(i)))) == k:
        rez.append(i)

if rez:
    print(f'Да: {rez}')
else:
    print(f'Нет')
```